# How to find directive name for given DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose you have some custom directive `myDirectiveA` and associated controller `myControllerA` with `replace : true` - it means that your custom directive name will not appear in DOM tree.

How to find a directive name in this case?

(Something like `angular.element($0)...` ?)

P.S. I know that replace:true is deprecated.

Comment: Why do you want to know the directive name?  There may be an alternate way to get at what you're trying to do.

Comment: @zero298 Sometimes I need to debug some defect in front-end and, therefore, I need to quickly find source code file for any DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a way to do this, so I assume it's not possible.
However, it's possible to get controller:

```
angular.element($0).controller()
```

or a component's controller

```
angular.element($0).scope().$ctrl
```